# Body overlaps fixed, horizontal nav bar up top - CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, overlap, nav

I have to make a website for an assignment, and I'm having a bit of trouble. I've created a navbar up the top, and it's in a fixed position. However, when I scroll, everything shows through it. What I want, is essentially for the webpage to start under the navbar, so it's there at the top, and when I click 'About Me', it doesn't have the title under the navbar, like in the second image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GiEH.png

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks.

```
#top-bar
    {   
        border-top:#fff dashed 1px;
        width:100%;
        height:32px;
        background:black;
        opacity:0.8;
        text-align:center;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        padding-bottom:12px;

    }

#top-nav li
{
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 49px;
    padding: 0px 14px;


}

#top-nav li a
{
    display:block;
    color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#top-nav li:hover, #top-nav li:hover a
{
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff;
}
```

and the html:

```
    <nav id="top-bar">
        <ul id="top-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#about-text">About Me</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#programming-text">Programming</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#home-text">Hometown</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#swinburne-text">Swinburne</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#achievement-text">Acheivements</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Basically, I don't want the webpage to 'scroll through' the nav bar.
Also, my class hasn't done javascript yet, so if there is a solution not using javascript that would be great.

Thanks guys.

P.S. Here is the code for the div for the about:

```
<div id="about-text" class="box">
    <h3>About Me</h3> 
    <p>My name is   , I'm 18 years old, and a Computer
    Science student at Swinburne University of Technology, Hawthorn.
    I've always been interested in computers, there is something
    beautiful about technology working to do so many things the human
    brain cannot possibly do.</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#about-text, #programming-text, #home-text, #achievement-text
{

    border-style : solid;
    border-width:0.2em;
    opacity:0.5;
    width : 70%;    
    transition: opacity 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;

}
```

Comment: Where is the code for your description layout?

Comment: @The-Val I've updated the question to include it, thanks

Comment: the css for `#top-nav` ?

Comment: Oops ><, Sorry, @Nelson it's there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you simply need to give the `.box`es enough of a `margin-top` for it to clear the fixed navbar.

**Update:**

Discovered that the root cause of the issue was the use of in-page links, which always scrolled right to the top of the viewport (under the fixed nav) when clicked.

The best solution ended up being adding empty `a` elements before each `div.box` to use as the target of the links, and give those a large enough size that the `.box` would fall into place below the navbar:

```
<a href="#about-text" class="button"></a>
<div class="box"> ... </div>

.button {
    display: block;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I've added: `.box { margin: 64px auto; }`, which allows the box to be cleared of the navbar when entering the page, but after scrolling, it still 'scrolls through' the navbar, and overlaps.

Comment: Ah, yes. Try removing the `opacity` property from `#top-bar` and add `z-index: 10`. That should ensure that the content goes under the navbar, and that nothing shows through.

Comment: That essentially works, nothing 'shows through' the navbar, however, it's still apparent that there is data above it, as when I click on a heading 'About me', 'Programming', etc, the top of the box is UNDER the navbar. Hmmm... :/

Comment: Ohhh, it finally clicked. You're using in-page links, not going to new pages. Ok, then instead of top margin on `.box`, make it padding.

Comment: Indeed. One more thing to try: remove the top padding and add: `position: relative;` and `top: 64px;` to the `.box` properties.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either :/. I'm not sure why this is such a hard problem to figure out, me and my friend were trying to figure it out for hours earlier too. Hmm, do you think I could wrap everything in a div, and set its height to be just under the bottom of the nav bar?

Answer (score 0):

One trick that you can use is to put `nav` within the `header` tag and give background color for header, white or whichever color you are using. Scrolling down will go below the nav bar but it wont be seen due to the background color which overlaps it.